# JQuery DOM POST

Tags: jquery, dom

```
var hashurl = function(ctrl, func,params,callback){
    $.post("/index.php/"+ctrl+"/"+func,params, function(data){
        callback(data);
    });
}
var bind = function(hashtag, ctrl, func, block, params){
    $(document).on("click","a[href="+hashtag+"]", function(){
    $(block).hide();
    hashurl(ctrl, func,params, function(data){
        $(block).html(data);
    });
    $(block).fadeIn("slow");

    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#auth").hide();
    $("#cloud").click(function(){
        $("#cloud").fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $("#auth").fadeIn("slow", function(){});
        });
    });

    bind("#log-in", "users", "login", "#auth", {login: $("#name").val()});

});
```

This is my JS code. When I have opened my page, I see cloud (logo). I must click on it. After I have clicked on cloud, I will see **Authenticate form**.  I write login and click on **a[href=#log-in]**. I have troubles with `bind("#log-in", "users", "login", "#auth", {login: $("#name").val()});` This function works good, but this not send POST information `{login: $("#name").val()}`

If I write some like: `bind("#log-in", "users", "login", "#auth", {login: "hello"});` Then it works good. And my PHP script get POST data...

P.S Sorry for my English.

Comment: Well, what is in the #name element? Also, seeing the relevant HTML would help.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
bind("#log-in", "users", "login", "#auth", {login: $("#name").val()});
```

will get the value of `#name` at the point the page loads; if the user is entering that value after page load then it's not going to be in the object literal passed to your `params` parameter.

You'll need to modify your `bind` function so that it gets the value when the link is clicked, not on page load.